# Install apk from java code without user confirmation

Tags: android, sdk, installation, apk

I want to install an apk file from java code. I want to do this silently without any action from user. I try this code ..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(files[i].toString())), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

It works but wants the user to confirm the installation. 
I try

```
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm -s install "+files[i].toString()+"\"");
```

but doesn't work 
i have given these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: why do you want to install without notifying user...?

Comment: because this is the purpose of the application.
browse for files in /sdcard and then install it
this app will not be upload on market it is for personal use

Comment: Can't understand the down votes.. After all plenty of research behind this question..

Comment: for personal purpose only, I prefer pushing to `/system`, it's faster and better..

Comment: how to push the app i wont to install in /system ?

Comment: if it is for personal use, then why do you want to install without notification... it sounds like inserting some bugs into user phone with out notifying them... ??? 

and I hope you can't push something into '/system' unless the devices is already rooted... correct me if i m wrong...

Comment: i found how to install .apk file in /system folder it`s very easy end isn`t need to use any permission, but device must be rooted